# return data to the webview using javascript channels

Tags: javascript, flutter, webview

I'm a beginner working on flutter and I started to working with the webview_flutter component https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

I want to stablish a bidirectional communication with the webview component in order to provide access to certain variables stored in the local storage using an object that I created.

For this I inject a simple js like this

```
function myCustomObj() {
    this.getName = function() { return jsBridge.postMessage("GET_NAME_FUNCTION"); };
}

window.myCustomObj = new myCustomObj();
```

and I setup the webview plugin as this

```
    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageFinished: (String url) async {
            var jsBridge = await _getJavascriptFileFromAsset(assetFilePath: 'myjsAsset.js);
            controller.runJavaScript(jsBridge);
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..clearCache()
      ..clearLocalStorage()
      ..addJavaScriptChannel('jsBridge', onMessageReceived: (callback) {
          //Get data from localStorage and send it back to js?
      })
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.initialUrl));
```

So anyone who access or call to window.myCustomObj.getName() can access to a value stored in the device.

Is there any way to return data back to the js using the javascript channel? I tried to return a promise but the value is always null or undefined.

Send data back to javascript with the javascript channel

Comment: Any luck @user2708880 on solution? I am also looking to postMessage()